# How to evaluate a WinForms CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for a good way to evaluate what is checked in a WinForms CheckedListBox.

I filled the box using the WYSIWYG editor in VS2008 and added values into it. I'd like to run a switch statement to control code execution based on which box is checked. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Use GetItemChecked() to find out if an item is checked, CheckedIndices or CheckedItems to get an array of all checked items.  Write an event handler for the ItemCheck event to find out when the user modified the checked state of an item.  Easy peasy, this is well described in the MSDN article for CheckedListBox.  Keep it close at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditemcollection.aspx):

```
foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    string itemName = itemChecked.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(itemName + " is checked.");
}
```

There are several other ways to review the state of a CheckedListBox. Review the [MSDN documentation of that class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell u the best way knowing so little of your specs. Surely you can loop through the listbox items and start some actions depending on what is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate checked checkbox using the below code. my checked list contains both text and value coming from database. Here , menu is my checkedlist name

```
foreach (DataRowView  itemChecked in  menu.CheckedItems)
            {
              string itemName = itemChecked["MenuName"].ToString();
              int id=Convert.ToInt32(itemChecked["MenuID"].ToString());

              }
```